# A textview with the string wrapping to at most one more line

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` and I would like for the text to wrap around at most 1 line if it is too long.
I tried:

```
android:minLines="1"  
android:maxLines="2"
```

but these work only if the text has actual new lines.
If I use:

```
android:lines="2"
```

it works but when the text has few chars the textview still takes space for 2 lines.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: for maxLines to work, textView needs to know your actual views width. Either use 'match_parent' or give size of textView in dp or use ConstraintLayout and use constraints to fix the width of textView. Then use `android: maxLines ="1"`

Comment: @RahulKumar:I have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. But the text seems to be cut off instead of wrapping. It works as I want only with `android:lines="2"`

Answer (score 1):

Textview must have width if you want use maxLines param.
Try this maybe it works:

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
```

Also you can use android:maxLength if your Textview's parent has a max or constant size

Edit base on comments:
set TextView width in runtime

```
String myString = "test";
    textView.measure(0, 0);
    View parent = (View) textView.getParent();
    parent.measure(0, 0);
    int currentWidth = textView.getWidth();
    int maxAvailableWidth = parent.getWidth();
    int finalWidth = (int) (myString.length() * textView.getTextSize() * factor); // factor is depends on your typeface
    if(finalWidth > maxAvailableWidth)
        finalWidth = maxAvailableWidth;
    textView.setWidth(finalWidth);
```

Thanks

Comment: I have width set to `match_parent`

Comment: So it must work correctly. I thought you need wrap_content! Do you have still problem?!

Comment: Yes that works only if my string has a new line char. It is is a long string of chars it just cuts them out and does not wrap to a second line

Comment: Try these things:1. add android:ellipsize="end" 2.set a defult text in xml like: android:text="test" 3.trim your String before set in TextView. if these won't work please say what's your TextView parent

Comment: Try what things?

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter while typing :D

Comment: TextView parent is LinearLayout wrap_content/wrap_content

Comment: set match_parent for LinearLayout width too, if LinearLayout is in a ScrollView, scrollView's width must be match_parent too

Comment: LinearLayout is in a horizontal RecyclerView

Comment: Give an actual width to the TextView for example android:layout_width="100dp", if it fixed that the problem is from viewHolder. If you share your full xml and a part of your adapter will be easier to fix the problem

Comment: Using the size trick it ended up wrapping. I'll paste sample. But what is your suspicion on this?

Comment: The holder just sets the text

Comment: It depends on some parameters, for example if you use Grid as RecycelerView's decoration you must set size of RecycleView's children in onCreateViewHolder, because if TextView hasn't actual size, it size set depends on first String lenght and other Strings will not change the TextView's params size, another way is to call  TextView recheck its size each time you set new String and that's not recommended if you have many children in view.

Comment: How can I call TextView recheck its size each time you set new String ?

Comment: after setText call invalidate(), also you can use measure() and set TextView Size pro grammatically base on max available width and String length. If my answers were useful please vote it :)

Comment: Upvoted! Could you please put an example of the `measure` in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in my code and it works. you will need to use only `maxlines` and set width to `match_parent`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"/>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works only if you have a new line in the text. I am talking about a text that is too long and should wrap to a second line

Comment: this works for long text as well, check update answer

Comment: can you post your xml code, there might be something else going on.

Comment: Your example works only if the text has new line char

Comment: @jim : you can see attached image it, there is no newline character in input.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Just shows the text in 1 line and ellipsis at the end

Comment: I had to misunderstand the wrap question. Do you want to achieve 2 lines at most ? If so, change to `maxLines="2"`